# Laravel Validation of Umlaute

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm using laravel 4 for an app, where I want to validate a form which contains the country Österreich (austria). On my development server it works perfectly, but on the live system it just won't, but I cant figure out why ...

the validation rule is quite simple

```
'land' => array('required',"in:Österreich")
```

or

```
'land' => 'required','in:Österreich'
```

both versions work on the dev- but not on the live-server

anyone who figured this out already or has a clue for me? o.O

Comment: Might have something to do with the encoding of the server, check the encoding in php.ini maybe?

Comment: good idea, but it doesn't seem to be the reason. i set both to utf-8 and it is still not working :(

Comment: Could you check your page with this [W3C checker](http://validator.w3.org/i18n-checker/), it could give you hints about missing UTF-8 meta tags, or if your php file is not UTF-8 encoded.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a work around with the regex validation of laravel. here what you can do

```
array('required',"regex:/(Österreich|Italien)/")
```

hope it works for everyone :)

Comment: I still would like to know what was the problem though :(

Comment: There is a difference between "in" and "regex" in the validator, see: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.0/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php#L1560

For "regex", a normal array is returned and validated with `preg_match`. The "in" validation does work with `str_getcsv` for the parameters. Mix that with some special characters and different server setups and things go boom.